# Proof there is no instance for a given UML-Diagram

Tags: uml, proof, cardinality

Given the diagram in the top-right corner, I'm supposed to decide whether there is any valid instance of it. Now the given image is a counterproof by example ('wegen' means 'because of'). The counterproof uses the cardinality ('Mächtigkeit') of the objects.

I don't understand, why for example 2*|A| equals |C|, as in UML, A would be in relation with 2 objects of C (rel1). So for every A there have to be 2 C to make a valid instance. 2*|A| = |C| should therefore be |A| = 2*|C|.

Why is it the other way around?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `2*|A| = |C|` since there is double the amount of `C` objects compared to `A` because each `A` has  two `C` associated.
- `|A| = |B|` because they have a 1-1 relation
- `3*|C| = 2*|B|` because each `C` has 3 `B` and each `B` has 2 `C`
- (4) and (5) are just substitutions where the last gives a contradiction

q.e.d

P.S. As @ShiDoiSi pointed out there is no `{unique}` constraint in the multiplicities. This will make it possible to have multiple associations to the same instance. Ergo, you have 1-1 relations. So with that being the case you actually **CAN** have a valid instantiation of the model.

Now go and tell that to your teacher xD

Comment: Hm, where does it say that one A has to be associated to two *distinct* Cs in the diagram? I don't remember if there's a graphical notation for that (one can probably abuse composition), or if you would have to go to OCL for that. That said, your counter-example/proof is fine of course if one assumes this.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi You are probably right. Distinct is shown as `{unique}`. So with the constraint that you choose non-distinct (i.e. identical) instances you can have a valid instantiation of the model. Well spotted! I'll make an amendment.